# How to traverse in project followed by 'by' step for required number of times in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am having a vertex(say Province). I am using a property called code from that vertex to traverse through the in-between edge.

```
gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').project('state','city').by(values('code')).by(coalesce(inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','city').project('cityId','cityName'),constant('NONE')))

==>{state=DD, city=NONE}
==>{state=HR, city={cityId=e2d437ca-0150-47fd-bbbe-2a04d697db9a, cityName=Gurugram}}
==>{state=JK, city=NONE}
==>{state=CH, city=NONE}
==>{state=MZ, city=NONE}
==>{state=OR, city=NONE}
==>{state=TR, city=NONE}
==>{state=UP, city={cityId=5b871eed-2bfd-4959-81b1-81151d238ed4, cityName=Lucknow}}
==>{state=ML, city=NONE}
==>{state=AR, city=NONE}
==>{state=AS, city=NONE}
==>{state=GA, city=NONE}
==>{state=JH, city=NONE}
==>{state=PY, city=NONE}
==>{state=RJ, city=NONE}
==>{state=WB, city=NONE}
==>{state=AN, city=NONE}
==>{state=AP, city=NONE}
==>{state=GJ, city=NONE}
==>{state=HP, city=NONE}
==>{state=MN, city=NONE}
==>{state=PB, city=NONE}
==>{state=UT, city=NONE}
==>{state=BR, city=NONE}
==>{state=CT, city=NONE}
==>{state=DN, city=NONE}
==>{state=DL, city={cityId=f715b5d9-96b5-4907-a4b4-91eb2fdd0022, cityName=New Delhi}}
=>{state=KA, city={cityId=5f37f9e9-bed0-4a9f-9bec-bb296672e579, cityName=Bengaluru}}
==>{state=KL, city=NONE}
==>{state=LD, city=NONE}
==>{state=MP, city=NONE}
==>{state=MH, city={cityId=256c974a-c4f7-4145-bc26-43566cfa9009, cityName=Mumbai}}
==>{state=NL, city=NONE}
```

In the output which i have tried, has properties of only one city.
In some of the states,we are having more than a city. But I am not getting the two city data's. How can I approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `fold()` within the `by()`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').
  inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').
  project('state','city').
    by(values('code')).
    by(coalesce(inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').
                has('type','city').
                project('cityId','cityName').
                  by('cityId').by('cityName').
                fold(),
       constant('NONE')))
```

Note that you can simplify a little bit to:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').
  in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').
  project('state','city').
    by('code').
    by(coalesce(__.in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').
                has('type','city').
                valueMap('cityId','cityName').
                  by(unfold()).
                fold(),
       constant('NONE')))
```

`by()` will only `next()` the anonymous child traversal given to it as an argument so if you have more than one result expected you need to provide your own reducing operation (e.g. `fold()`, `count()`, etc)